# How to disable DevTools in Atom Shell

Tags: javascript, electron

I've been trying to figure out how to disable the devtools in [Atom Shell](https://github.com/atom/atom-shell).  I've tried using a window event listener to no avail.  It seems that the [devtools-opened window event listener](https://github.com/atom/atom-shell/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#event-devtools-opened) doesn't work.  The devtools are still openable by `Command+Option+I` shortcut.

```
mainWindow.on('devtools-opened', function(){
    mainWindow.closeDevTools();
});
```

In the end I went with [Mousetrap](http://craig.is/killing/mice) and had to use a `e.preventDefault()` on a `Cmd+Shift+I` shortcut listener.  I'd rather not have to include the Mousetrap library if it's unnecessary but as of yet I can find nothing.

Does anyone know of a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you install a custom menu (i.e. overriding the default Atom Shell menu?) Once you do this, you'll actually have to explicitly implement the Devtools shortcut to get it to work.